# How does GetCommState populate the DCB struct in Windows 10 when using usbser.sys CDC ACM driver

Tags: windows, serial-port, embedded

I am building a embedded device that will communicate to the outside world by virtual COM. I have the descriptor and all the callbacks for the USB set up correctly and COM is working - well kind of. The problem is that when I issue the GetCommState command for the COM I get a semi valid struct back and when one fixes only couple of parameters (like setting the speed and 8N1) and try to reconfigure the port by calling SetCommState the actions fails with: 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.'

If one continues to use the port it just work - all writes and reads - without a problem. But the issue is that most libraries try to reconfigure the port by first issuing the GetCommState and then SetCommState - pyserial and C# both do it in this way.

My question is where do the "default" configuration for COM comes form?

In the USB ACM CDC standard there are (optional) class requests for SET and GET COMM feature but I can see (from USB sniffer) that they are never called (I tried with capabilities for USB ACM CDC set to 0x06 (that is without SET/GET COMM) and 0x07 (with SET/GET COMM) but in no case I get a class request from the driver). So the driver must take the config from somewhere else, does anybody knows from where or how?

I am using an NXP LPC and Windows 10 with usbser.sys driver on other end.

What I already checked is:

- compared the USB descriptor to the working one - they are the same
- checked the USB traffic - the enumeration and communication looks the same
- without doing GetCommState and SetCommState the COM is working without problem

I attached the content of the DCB struct for working sample (left) and my (right). I do not understand where do the marked values come from? Who sets them?

[image: Comparison between working sample and my code]

Comment: Windows issues the USB CDC ACM PSTN *GetLineCoding* request. The answer contains bit rate, parity etc. That's the basis for the `GetCommState()` result. In the configuration descriptor, the ACM capabilities are set to 2. It's difficult to be more specific without seeing the configuration descriptor, the USB traffic and possibly the code.

Comment: Why don't you look for it from the sample code and materials around here? [Serial driver samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/serial-driver-samples), [USB serial driver (Usbser.sys)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/blob/staging/windows-driver-docs-pr/usbcon/usb-driver-installation-based-on-compatible-ids.md), [Windows-driver-samples/serial/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/serial)

Comment: Have you initialised the DCB (e.g, `DCB commstate = {0};`)?  It seems likely that unused fields (because for example, you are not using hardware or software flow control) are not explicitly set and have undefined value.  In the left image you have hardware flow control/modem control signals enabled; in USB CDC ACM that has no real effect; it is used in "USB-Serial" bridging applications to control the behaviour of the bridge UART - similarly with other parameters such as baud rate; they have no impact on the USB comms but can be processed by your device if the application requires it.

Comment: @Clifford: The Windows documentation states that `GetCommState()` should be called before using `SetCommState()`. That's the best practice for inintializing the field, and this seems to be applied here. And baud rate, parity etc. are relevant if a USB-to-serial bridge is used. So *usbser.sys* and USB CDC ACM do handle them. If they have non-sensible values, something is indeed wrong.

Comment: @Codo : re the relevance of baud-rate, parity etc, I did not say any different.  The signal/control packets are indeed sent, but the device may not use them.  I assume the device is the USB controller of the NXP LPC MCU not a USB-serial bridge.  If you were to use the NXP LPC MCU as a serial bridge, they would of course be used.  My point is that in the right-hand side image both hardware and software flow control are disabled, so the related settings such as XON/XOFF characters are irrelevant.  The question then perhaps becomes one of why/how flow control is used on one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

The settings should come from the port driver - you can view and set default values in the Windows Device Manager. In your case, it would seem that flow control with RTS/CTS is enabled (left picture), which might be something that your USB adapter uses internally. If it works, then leave those settings as they were.

I'd advise to do like this:

- Always check the result of each API function you call!
- Call `CreateFile` to get the port handle.
- Optionally call `GetCommTimeouts` and store the result in a zero-initialized struct like `COMMTIMEOUTS com_timeouts = {0};`. Change members of the struct as needed, then call `SetCommTimeouts`.
- Create an (almost) zero-initialized struct `DCB dcb = { .DCBlength = sizeof(DCB) }`.
- Call `GetCommState` on this struct.
- Set baudrate, parity, stop bits etc as required. Leave other members as they were.
- Call `SetCommState`.